# Pending requests with Python's SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, asynchronous, httprequest, simplehttpserver

I'm making an anonymous chat application, similar to Omegle. My method of approach instead of using sockets is to use a REST API, but to add a bit of a twist. When a user makes a request, such as POST /search (find a match), the request is held by the server until another user sends a POST /search. Once two people have done this, both requests are responded to which lets the client know to switch to a chat page. This is also done with a pending GET /events request, which is only responded to by the server if there's any new events to be sent.

This works very well in theory with the flow of this application; however, since I'm using SimpleHTTPServer - which is a very basic library - requests are not handling asynchronously. This means that if I block one request until information requirements are fulfilled, no other requests can be accepted. For this kind of project I really don't want to take the time to learn an entirely new library/sub-language for asynchronous requests handling, so I'm trying to figure out how I can do this.

```python
def waitForMatch(client):
    # if no other clients available to match:
    if not pendingQueue:
        # client added to pending queue
        pendingQueue.append(client)
        client["pending"] = True

        while client["pending"]:
            time.sleep(1)

        # break out and let the other client's waitForMatch call create the chatsession
        return

    # now there's a client available to match
    otherClient = pendingQueue.pop()
    otherClient["pending"] = False

    # chat session created
    createChatSession(otherClient, client)
```

This is the code I currently have, which won't work with non-async requests.

Comment: No, it doesn't. First of all, the while loop doesn't break until a second client is introduced. The while loop doesn't wait until the pendingQueue has something, it waits until the first client is no longer pending (triggered by second client). Second, there's a return which catches the first client and cleanly exits it while the second function call sets up the session between the two clients.

Comment: If you don't want another library to handle long-polling, then you are going to have to do a standard REST api without long polling. Do client-side polling (inefficient but good enough for messing around) to check if the room is full or if you have received messages.